# PHP5: Callbacks between Class Objects

Tags: php, oop, closures

I am trying to understand how far I can go with PHP5's closures/callbacks, but I am currently trapped in a glass case of "why doesn't this work".

In the following example, I understand that the use of `$this` in a callback (especially when the scope changes) isn't going to work, it's just there to show you how I hope to be able to use callbacks/closures.

```
class Customer {
  public $name = '';
  public $callback = NULL;

  function __construct($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
  }
  function when_enters($callback) {
    $this->callback = $callback;
  }
  function enter_store() {
    if(is_callable($this->callback))
      call_user_func($this->callback);
  }
}

class Salesman {
  public $customer = NULL;

  function add_customer(&$customer) { 
    $this->customer =& $customer;
    $this->customer->when_enters(function() {
      $this->greet_customer();
    });
  }
  function greet_customer() {
    echo "Hello, {$this->customer->name}!";
  }
}
$salesman = new Salesman();
$customer = new Customer('John');
$salesman->add_customer(&$customer);
$customer->enter_store();
```

I have been able to reproduce this basic functionally by implementing `Salesman` as a static class and setting the callback function as `Salesman::greet_customer` instead of `$this->greet_customer()`.

Basically, what I want to know is... using object instances, is this kind of functionality possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In php, `call_user_func` can accept a two-element array to call a method on a class. So if you do this:

```
$this->customer->when_enters(array($this,'greet_customer'));
```

it will do what you want. Another alternative on PHP 5.3.0 or greater is to use a closure along with a local copy of `$this`:

```
$this_copy=$this;
$this->customer->when_enters(function() use ($this_copy) {
    $this_copy->greet_customer();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have some good news, and some bad news.

The good news is that the next major release of PHP (5.4?) will permit anonymous functions to be properties of a class, and be callable without jumping through hoops, *and* [will allow you to reference `$this` by binding the function to a specific context](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures/object-extension#status_as_of_august_10_2010).

The bad news is that nobody seems to know when the PHP trunk will be turned into a release.

Now, given that you can't actually reference `$this` inside the anonymous function, what you can do here is very limited.  One option would be to pass the current object to the function:

```
function enter_store() {
  if(is_callable($this->callback))
    call_user_func($this->callback, $this);
}
```

While this will work, and allow you to poke at the object from the function, you'd be limited to methods and properties labeled `public`.  This may or may not be an issue for you.

Comment: thanks for the link. it really helped alot and I found a ton more to read on the subject. it lead me to [this *bug* report](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49543), which was pretty much the exact same workaround @Anomie pointed to. had to give it to them... but thanks again. :)